# How to use volume in docker compose for postgres?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Here is the [image](https://github.com/andreagrandi/postgresql-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) I am using.

I named it `posgres_test`

If I run the image individually

```
docker run -i -t -v="test_volume:/var/lib/postgresql" -p 5432:5432 posgres_test
```

I can access it with

```
psql -h 192.168.99.100 -p 5432 -U pguser -W pgdb
```

Or I can access it with my golang app

```
// host is set to postgres
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://pguser:pguser@postgres:5432/pgdb")
// table test_db is manually created.
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM test_db WHERE)
```

However if I use `docker compose`

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"
services:
  postgres:
    image: my_image/postgresql:9.3
    volumes:
      - test_volume:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  web:
    image: my-golang-app4
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
volumes:
  test_volume: {}
```

I get the following

```
pguser@pgdb ERROR:  relation "test_db" does not exist at character 15
```

I know for sure `test_db` exist in `test_volume` since

```
docker run -i -t -v="test_volume:/var/lib/postgresql" -p 5432:5432 posgres_test
psql -h 192.168.99.100 -p 5432 -U pguser -W pgdb

\dt
```

will show the table I created

But it seems like my app in docker compose cannot find it

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 37):

**About your docker-compose file**

1. First, I thought it's because you don't use the 'links' option to link your postgres container to the web container - it's good practice if you don't expand ports - but you expand postgres port.
2. If you want to use inheritance from the image you posted

   Instead of using this line:

   > my_image/postgresql:9.3

   use:

   ```
   docker/postgres
   ```

   and create path `docker/postgres` and there place `Dockerfile` with inheritance from the container you want.
3. I always use shared volumes in `docker-compose.yml` like this:

   ```
   .:/var/www/html
   ```

   where `.` is my project path where I place my code files.

**Image I created to test this case**

I don't have all your docker files structure to reproduce this error and fix it, so I created a `docker-compose`, which should match your needs or help to fix your issue:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: docker/web
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - dbpostgres 
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html   # I will share my code so I map this path
  dbpostgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - /private/var/lib/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: pguser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pguser
      POSTGRES_DB: pgdb
```

Notes:

1. I will recommend use official postgres image
2. I left comments next to the lines.

How I made connection:

```
host=dbpostgres port=5432 dbname=pgdb user=pguser password=pguser
```

Because my web container knows host dbpostgres (image name and domain name) now - I link them using links.

**If you need database from existing container**

If you need the database from your existing container just use the docker option `cp` to copy database locally:

```
docker cp posgres_test:/var/lib/postgresql /private/var/lib/postgresql
```

where `/private/var/lib/postgresql` is a path on your localhost.
You also need to change credentials to db in docker-compose to your old credentials.
You have to do it before running `docker-compose` because if db doesn't exist, it will be created.

*Any questions, let me know.*

Comment: Could you please explain why do we need this environtment vars in docker-compose?

Comment: You can just omit it. We just need it when we want to set up database user, password and database name created at the starting container.

Answer (score 11):

If the volume is external and already existing before the use of docker-compose you should declare it external, or else docker compose will create a new volume with the project name as prefix.

```
volumes:
  test_volume:
   external: true
```

Docs for `external` using compose v3 (mostly similar to [v2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#external)): https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#external

Answer (score 1):

I think it sould be something like this for you.

```
docker run -itd -p 5432:5432 --name postgres_test -v /path/in/your/host :/path/in/your/container postgres_test psql -h 192.168.99.100 -p 5432 -U pguser -W pgdb
```

Read Docker docs(https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/), watch tutorials (there is a Docker Youtube channel whith great tutorials).

Comment: I am already able to to access volume when I run docker container individually, (eg. `docker run -i -t -v="test_volume:/var/lib/postgresql" -p 5432:5432 posgres_test`) the problem arises when I use docker compose

Comment: Nevermind, I missunderstood yesterday ^^'

But I saw that in your post your docker-compose.yml don't have `version: 'x'` into it, and if I remember well by default docker-compose take version 1 in this case and volume configuration doesn't work... Try to put `version: '2'`.
I hope it will work :)

Comment: Hmmm... Did you tried without `volumes:
  test_volume: {}` in your compose file and putting the complete path or just  `/var/lib/postgresql` ? I've never used it until now so I don't really know how it's meant to be used... And if it doesn't help you I can't help you to fix this... :/